# Improper handling of extended ASCII characters with jdbc

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, ascii, sybase, jconnect

I am using JDBC to connect to a Sybase table that contains extended ascii characters (ascii code >= 128). 
And they are returned as `?`.

I am calling this from Dot Net for Apache Spark using JConn4. The sybase database is using iso_1.

In another test I was able to make ODBC show the character correctly by instructing ODBC to not use character conversion.

How could I make jdbc read the extended ascii characters properly?

Comment: "extended ASCII" is a very loose term that means a character set that is based on ASCII and provides a mapping to other characters for bytes 128-255. It doesn't mean anything without knowing the explicit character set to use. You may also want to look at http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0707/html/prjdbc0707/BHCFJECE.htm (and its sub-topics).

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the link Mark Rotteveel, I tried a few things from there: 
Changed the JCONNECT_VERSION
Set DISABLE_UNICHAR_SENDING to False
Previously I had tried 
.Option("CHARSET", "iso_1")
Option("JAVA_CHARSET_MAPPING ", "cp1252")
To declare a mapping between what I have in Sybase and what I understand to be the equivalent mapping. 
But none of this worked. Any other suggestions?
Thank you,
Waldemar

Comment: I don't use Sybase myself, so I can't help you other than what I suggested earlier.